# Delete unmanaged files of a directory via Puppet

Tags: puppet

I've made a small module that is able to create pools for php-fpm in hiera and saves them on the nodes in /etc/php5/fpm.d/.
Every node (and therefore pool.conf file) is generated by a resource in Puppet.

My hiera looks like this

```
phpfpm::pools:
  poolname:
    listen: '127.0.0.1:9000'
    some:   'other'
  anotherpoolname:
    listen: '127.0.0.1:9001'
    other:  'value'
```

Now, I have the problem that I don't know how to autoremove all files, that haven't been created by puppet. E.g. if a user creates manual a new conf file in /etc/php5/fpm.d/, it should be removed by puppet.

I alredy tried purge in module, but it deletes every file except the one that will be created in the current resource.

Any advices?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not certain I understand how your code works, but I think you need to do something similar to what I did here to purge the yum.repos.d directory:

Hiera:

```
profile::base::yum::repos:
  'C7.0.1406-base':
    ensure: 'present'
    baseurl: 'http://vault.centos.org/7.0.1406/os/$basearch/'
    descr: 'CentOS-7.0.1406 - Base'
    enabled: '0'
    gpgcheck: '1'
    gpgkey: 'file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-7'
  'C7.0.1406-centosplus':
    ensure: 'present'
    baseurl: 'http://vault.centos.org/7.0.1406/centosplus/$basearch/'
    descr: 'CentOS-7.0.1406 - CentOSPlus'
    enabled: '0'
    gpgcheck: '1'
    gpgkey: 'file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-7'
```

Manifest:

```
class profile::base::yum (
  Hash [String, Hash[String, String]] $repos,
) {
  Yumrepo {
    stage => 'pre',
  }
  create_resources(yumrepo, $repos)

  # Since we must purge the file resources in
  # /etc/yum.repos.d/, we must also declare the 
  # associated files to prevent them also
  # being purged.

  keys($repos).each |String $yumrepo| {
    file { "/etc/yum.repos.d/${yumrepo}.repo": }
    ->
    Yumrepo[$yumrepo]
  }
  file { '/etc/yum.repos.d/':
    ensure  => directory,
    recurse => true,
    purge   => true,
  }
}
```

Comment: This is just what I was about to suggest -- i.e. manage the containing directory via a `File` resource with `recurse` and `purge` both `true`.  Per [its docs](https://docs.puppet.com/puppet/latest/type.html#file-attribute-purge), `purge` will cause unmanaged files to be deleted, and *only* unmanaged ones.  In particular, files managed via separate `File` resources are not subject to purging.

Comment: I think the `yumrepo` staging and metaparameters in the code is a bit unnecessary to answer this question. That being said, this should absolutely work, but the question ambiguously said something about trying something like this and it not working. This definitely answers the question as stated though.

Comment: True. The code sample could be confusing if Puppet's ordering is not understood well. That said, the chances are that someone finding this in the archives will be here for yum.repos.d problem anyway, so I think it makes sense to leave the full working example up.